# How to identify a variable-sized zone by a point given by coordinate?

Tags: algorithm, math, geolocation, location, geometry

A map is partitioned into zones of variable sizes using longitude and latitude.

For simplicity, let us consider the map as the Cartesian plane and longitude and latitude as x,y-coordinate.

A zone is always a rectangle. For example, a zone can be represented like x∈(0,3],y∈(30,50]
The range in the Cartesian plane is finite but very large.

Then, when given an x,y-coordinate, how can we identify the zone that coordinate belongs to?

For example, when we have an x,y-coordinate (2, 36), how do we effectively find that this belongs to the zone x∈(0,3],y∈(30,50]?

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward: `if (x >= 0 and x < 3 and y >= 30 and y < 50){in_the_zone = true;}`

Comment: It seems straightforward, but in fact it is not.

Comment: Please elaborate. Is my proposed method somehow not adequate?

Comment: You have tens of thousands of zones, and you have the list of ranges of x,y-coordinates for those zones. When you are given (x,y) = (2,36), which is a user's location, you have to effectively do a search for the zone it belongs to. It is not obvious that the location belongs to the zone x∈(0,3],y∈(30,50]. A naive way to do this is to walk through every zone in the list, but this will be too slow. If it was one-dimensional, maybe we can store the means of the zone ranges in a binary search tree and do a quick lookup and compare a few, but it is two-dimensional and this complicates the problem

Comment: The data structure you need is called an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

Comment: @Heuster Thank you for your answer. Can you explain a little bit more, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment, you could solve this problem using an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). The linked wiki article gives a way better explanation than I can presume to give, but the basic concept is really simple:

Given a set of regions `R0` (rectangles in your example), you construct a set `R1` of *fewer* regions, by grouping the original regions and computing their bounding rectangles.

As an example, consider the following set of regions (I want to keep the notation simple, that's why I only consider squares on the diagonal: by `(p, s)` I mean a square whose lower left corner is at `(p, p)` and whose sides have length `s`):

```
R0 = {(0, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)}
```

We can now group the first two and the last two regions and compute their bounding rectangles to get to `R1`:

```
R1 = {(0, 2), (3, 2)}
```

The trick is now that, given a query point `(1.5, 1.5)` we don't have to check all regions in `R0`. We first perform the query on `R1`, and find that the point lies within the region `(0, 2)`. We thus only have to search on in the *children* of that bounding rectangle, which are the first two regions in `R0`.

---

Of course, this was a very simple example. In practise, you want to have only few (some low constant number, like, 4) regions of `R0` in each bounding rectangle in `R1`. So when you have many input regions, there will still be many rectangles in `R1`. Fortunately, we can just apply the same trick again, and create a smaller set of bounding rectangles `R2` out of `R1`. And so on, until you reach a set `Rn`, which only contains a few rectangles.

You have thus created a whole tree: the entire region is the root. Each rectangle in `Rn` is a top-level child, and so on.

Querying just works as I described for the simple example: you only need to recurse on rectangles that contain the query point, by which you would ideally exclude many other rectangles.

---

So why did I say *ideally*? Let's go back to the example and assume I grouped the first and the last rectangle, and the middle two. That would give me a different set of bounding rectangles:

```
R1 = {(0, 5), (1, 3)}
```

These rectangles are overlapping, so the same query point as above would be in *both* rectangles. That is, we would still need to inspect all regions of `R0`.

It is thus very important to divide your rectangles properly. The problem of finding an optimal division is NP-hard, so you'll have to use heuristics. A simple one would be to sort your rectangles by their left x-coordinate and divide them accordingly. In the next level you would do the same by y-coordinate. That method works pretty well when all rectangles are evenly spread and close to square.

Answer (score 1):

See Seidel's paper "A simple and fast incremental randomized algorithm for computing trapezoidal decompositions and for triangulating polygons" available at http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos528/handouts/A%20Simple%20and%20fast.pdf . A such trapezoidal decomposition of your set of rectangles will give O(log n) look up time to find the rectangle that contains a given query point, assuming you have n rectangles.